# How to add points with manual colour to a plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a complex plot `g` with ggplot with a number of series with different colors. Now, I'd like to add a few points with a manual color, without bothering about the colors of all the pre-existing series.

For example, if I do this

```
g + geom_point(data = dd, aes_string(x = xseries, y = yseries, color = "red" ) )
```

it doesn't work, obviously, because it's expecting a factor variable because it wants to associate colors to values of a variable in the data frame `dd`.
Another trial was to assign a variable to those points (say `redpoint`, so the data frame `dd`would contain columns "xseries", "yseries" and "redpoint") like this:

```
g + geom_point(data = dd, aes_string(x = xseries, y = yseries, color = "redpoint" ) )
```

Now, [people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363035/ggplot2-how-to-specify-multiple-fill-colors-for-points-that-are-connected-by-li) advice to use `scale_color_manual` to manually define colors. However, if I do that I should explicitly state all the colors of the data series that are in `g`, which is quite problematic as they are several tens and it took me a while to assign them the colors I want.
So, is there a method to add points with a manual color without specifying all the colors of the pre-existing plot?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks I have found a solution to my own question, actually.
The problem is solved by stating the color outside the `aes_string`, like

```
g + geom_point(data = dd, aes_string(x = xseries, y = yseries), color = "red" )
```

This seems to work fine.